# How to check list object is not null before using ForEach lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq

I want to know how can check list object is not null before using ForEach loop. Below is example code which I am trying:

```
List<string> strList   ;
strList.ForEach (x => Console.WriteLine(x)) ;
```

I looking for a solution in terms of lambda expression and do not want to use `if` statement.

Comment: You should avoid having a null list in the first place.  Whatever is generating the list should simply return an empty list, instead of `null`.

Comment: @GrantWinney You don't *have* to.  It's the *best* solution, but not the *only* solution.

Comment: Are you worried that `strList` is null, or that an element in `strList` is null?

Comment: a method is return strList object and somehow, I do not have control over it.

Comment: @JonB: I am saying strList object is null.

Comment: why down vote? Please provide a reason.

Comment: FYI - you can change that to `strList.ForEach(Console.WriteLine)`, since `Console.WriteLine` is already a method that takes a string and returns void.

Comment: @User1551892 Then transform the `null` list into an empty list as soon as it is returned from that external method, so that from then on you can use it as if it is non-null, rather than sticking `null` checks everywhere that object is used.

Comment: Let suppose, I am trying to something else. not printing in console.

Comment: But what you're asking (and hence the downvote) is how to check for null without checking for null. Avoiding an `if` is a completely arbitrary requirement that only serves to complicate things. Anything you do instead will ultimately just be syntactic sugar wrapping an `if`.

Comment: `strList?.ForEach (x => Console.WriteLine(x)) ;` should work

Comment: Perhaps that feature was not available 3 and half year back because no one came up with this solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can write an extension method for `List<>`, which will check for null and otherwise it will call `ForEach` on its `this` parameter. Call it ForEachWithNullCheck or something like this and you will be fine.

```
public static void ForEachWithNullCheck<T>(this List<T> list, Action<T> action)
{
  if (list == null)
  {
    // silently do nothing...
  }
  else
  {
    list.ForEach(action); 
  }
}
```

Usage example:

```
List<string> strList;
strList.ForEachWithNullCheck(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

Answer (score -1):

The most correct/idiomatic solution (if you cannot [avoid having a `null` collection to begin with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23112724/how-to-check-list-object-is-not-null-before-using-foreach-lambda-expression/23112806#comment35331210_23112724)) is to use an `if`:

```
if(list != null)
    foreach(var str in list)
        Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Putting the `if` into a lambda isn't going to make anything any easier.  In fact, it'll only create *more* work.

Of course if you *really* hate using an `if` you *can* avoid it, not that it'll really help you much:

```
foreach(var str in list??new List<string>())
    Console.WriteLine(str);
```

---

```
foreach(var str in list == null ? new List<string>() : list)
    Console.WriteLine(str);
```

You could emulate the more functional style `Maybe` concept with a method that invokes an action if the object isn't `null`, not that this is really any easier than a `null` check when dealing with actions instead of functions:

```
public static void Maybe<T>(this T obj, Action<T> action)
{
    if (obj != null)
        action(obj);
}
```

---

```
strList.Maybe(list =>
    foreach(var str in list)
        Console.WriteLine(str));
```

Answer (score -1):

You might have already got a better solution. Just wanted to show how I did it.

```
List<string> strList   ;
strList.ForEach (x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)?Console.WriteLine("Null detected"): Console.WriteLine(x)) ;
```

In my scenario I am summing up a value in a foreach as shown below.

```
double total = 0;
List<Payment> payments;
payments.ForEach(s => total += (s==null)?0:s.PaymentValue);
```

Comment: This does handle if an element of the list is null, but I don't think it's handling if the list itself is null. I get the null error on the ForEach itself.